# SQL Server license for Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, runtime, integration

We will need to configure "Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime" so that our prebuilt SSIS packages can connect to the Azure SQL databases in the cloud (cloud only).

While setting up the runtime, why is it asking for a SQL Server License when SSIS runtime has nothing to do with SQL Server?

Is it because it needs something similar to SSIS Catalog as it is in In-Premise setup? The need for a SQL Server license pushes the cost quite a bit especially when we need to renew it every year.

"Configuring Azure Integration Runtime and the need for a SQL Server License"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime

Comment: AFAIK, SSIS is included as long as you have a SQL Server license, means the remote instance must be licensed. On the contrary, the DEV edition is completely free which I guess does not apply for the Cloud.